# Concatenar uma string com número no TypeScript

Tags: string, angular, typescript, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando adicionar um 0 na formatação da minha data/mês, porém não estou conseguindo concatenar o 0 com a *string*.

Tentei algo como:

```
var dd = dataAtual.getDate();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
```

Recebo:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type "number"

Também tentei:

```
if (mm < 10) {
   mm = 0 + mm;
}
```

Mas desta maneira aparece apenas "6" no lugar de "06".

Comment: `dd.toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao contrário do JavaScript que tem tipagem fraca, TypeScript não permite coerção automática de tipos que possa trazer problemas em algumas circunstâncias, então a única forma de lidar com valores de tipos diferentes é convertendo um deles para compatibilizar, como você quer que seja texto deve criar uma `String` ou converter usando o método [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Tem uma outra questão. O fato da linguagem ser de tipagem estática, para o bem no meu ver, uma variável não pode trocar de tipo, então a variável que era número não pode receber um texto, então deve criar outra variável com o tipo `String` para receber os resultados.

Vou colocar em JS porque a sintaxe é idêntica em ambas linguagens, a semântica é que muda, a beleza do TS é justamente esta, não deixar um possível erro ocorrer, mais nada:

```js
function teste() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var d = "";
    var m = "";
    if (dd < 10)
        d = '0' + String(dd);
    if (mm < 10)
        m = '0' + String(mm);
    console.log(d);
    console.log(m);
}
teste();
```

Ou se preferir:

```js
function teste() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var d = "";
    var m = "";
    if (dd < 10)
        d = '0' + dd.toString();
    if (mm < 10)
        m = '0' + mm.toString();
    console.log(d);
    console.log(m);
}
teste();
```

Note que pode transformar o número em texto das duas formas como eu coloquei, eles são intercambiáveis, pode escolher qual achar melhor.

Se preferir pode fazer como o Valdeir falou e funciona bem em ambas linguagens, é uma forma até mais recomendável para solução genérica porque você terá problemas com os meses 10, 11 e 12:

```js
function teste() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var d = dd.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var m = mm.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    console.log(d);
    console.log(m);
}
teste();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Pad.ts).